# Limit number of rows displayed per group in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to filter top n rows per group in ag-grid-react? For example, I have applied sort on the price column and I want to see 5 highest-priced rows per group, is it possible to do this using some api or event handler?

Comment: you are using server side or client side model?

Comment: Client side model